# How to include files from remote server in Eclipse project without copy to local PC?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have to PC, one is server on Linux containing project files ( also build machine ) and another working desktop machine on WinXP. I want to create a project in Eclipse on my desktop machine without coping files to local machine, actually I want to be able to modify remote files and immediately run build, unlike modifying local files and synchronizing with remote project.Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mount a volume through SAMBA?

That's what I used to do prior to moving to Linux only.

Answer (score 0):

One caveat with using Samba mounts with Eclipse: if you are using libraries (like Google's licensing code, etc) there are problems with Samba mounts.   I couldn't get my project to work (using WinXP with a FreeBSD file server) with the licensing library (I would add the library, get a green checkmark and close the box... then when I'd open the box again, I'd get a red X...  I later found a posting that indicated this was a problem with Samba mounts and Eclipse, and when I copied everything to the local disk, it worked fine.)

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse plugin RSE ( remote system explorer ) allow to access and modify remote files without copying files locally